# why the program hang up when using ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I'm having an issue when using an `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Here is my code:

```
package study;

import org.pmw.tinylog.Logger;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1024);
        Producer producer = new Producer(queue);
        Consumer consumer = new Consumer(queue);

        new Thread(producer).start();
        new Thread(consumer).start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}

class Producer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue<String> queue = null;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
                queue.put(String.valueOf(i));
                //Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.info(e);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Logger.info(queue.take());
            //Logger.info(queue.take());
            //Logger.info(queue.take());
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Logger.info(e);
        }
    }
}
```

But the output is:

```
2016-10-24 14:08:27 [Thread-1] study.Consumer.run()
INFO: 0
```

I don't think this is correct, but I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Consumer`'s run to loop as at the moment you are only taking the first element off the queue, whilst the `Producer` has put **100000** into the queue.

```
 public void run() {
  while (true) {
    try {
        Logger.info(queue.take());
        //Logger.info(queue.take());
        //Logger.info(queue.take());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Logger.info(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While this fixes the issue - it's not an answer, you should add some details as to *why* this fixes the issue.

Comment: @Raniz OK Then.

Answer (score 0):

You run

```
Logger.info(queue.take());
```

only once, as a result, the consumer exit after getting ONE '0' from the queue. Just add a while loop like

```
while(true) {
    Logger.info(queue.take());
}
```